# slapd running fine and listening on port 389, but still can't contact

Tags: ldap, tcp, openldap, sasl, slapd

Here is my ldapsearch command with debug (I've masked my real IP address):

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/ldapsearch -H ldap://99.99.99.99 -b dc=my-domain,dc=com -x -d -1
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://99.99.99.99)
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://99.99.99.99:389/??base)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 99.99.99.99:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 99.99.99.99:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect errno: 110
ldap_close_socket: 3
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Yet, running `sudo /usr/local/bin/ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost -b dc=my-domain,dc=com -x` works just fine. I also did `netstat -plane | grep ":389"` and I get this printout:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:389             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          521074687  20249/slapd
tcp6       0      0 :::389                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          521074688  20249/slapd
```

Here is my `iptables -L -v` output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 10M packets, 938M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination      
 1349  294K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                  tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination      

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 10M packets, 982M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't test external connections like that when on the machine itself (some sort of loopback problems). Testing the connection from a different machine worked fine.